# Best algorithm for transforming public keys into user directory paths?

Tags: uniqueidentifier

I am making a communication system where users are identified by their public keys (asymmetric cryptography).  Essentially, each user ID is his public key.

But I need to create for them some directories where I store their messages.  Some directory layout like:

```
/storage/USERNAME/
    msg1
    msg2
    ...
```

But how to obtain `USERNAME`?  Technically, I don't want to prompt the user for it, since it is irrelevant.  It just needs to be a unique valid directory name.

I am considering to use a hashing algorithm, like `sha3`, to simply hash their public keys, and then use the result of the hash as their user identifier.  But not sure.  Is it an overkill?  Any better ideas?

---

***Update:** I used solution in the accepted answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/83546/using-first-say-50-letters-from-a-public-key-as-user-identifier/83548?noredirect=1#comment183530_83548) as well as the recommendation in its comments (i.e. to use sha3_244).*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [base62](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base62) encoding. It's much faster than sha3 and collision-free in that case.

As for many files in the folder it is also better to split storage to some subfolders parts. For example use two bytes of hash to generate subdirectories. So the user with id **ab**cdef1234 will be saved at the path /storage/ab/cdef1234/**

Comment: Hello new contributor!  Thanks for chiming in.  Not sure I fully understood.  Basically my concern is that public keys are a bit too long (100s of letters).  So if I base62-encode them (btw did you mean base64?), will it be too long?  Or did you mean that I should only use the 1st, say, 50 letters of the public key?

Comment: Maximum length of the filename depends on the filesystem you are using. For ext4 it is 255 bytes. Final string length after you encode your key depends on key length itself.
If you think that resulting strings may be larger that your filesystem limit, then you'd better split encoded string apart (f.e. by 50 letters) and make subfolders like this:
/storage/{first part of 50 letters}/{second part of 50 letters}/.../{end part} . 

About base64. You cant use base64 because it utilizes slashes which is not possible for filenames. So it is not a mistake: you should use base62, not base64.

Comment: To be clear. When you are encoding your key, you should encode binary data, not converted to ascii. Then your based62-string will always be the same length for all keys (if you are using keys with the same length of course)